# How to understand the relationship between these two geometrical structures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, string-theory, quantum-information, hilbert-space

During my study of quantum information processing, I occasionally meet two different geometrical structures:

- (a) The geometry of the Hilbert space of quantum state, where the superposition and entanglement are embedded, as discussed in the book "Geometry of quantum states"; and
- (b) the geometrical structures in the string physicists' work to describe our universe, which I am not that familiar with.

It seems that on one hand they are more or less independent so that we can solely discuss one without the other. For example we can talk about the properties of entanglement without mentioning what kind of particles carrying the entanglement; or the existence of entanglement does not depend on anything from the super string theory. On the other hand, they are sometimes closely related, especially when we are talking about blackhole information paradox, holographic entanglement entropy, ER=EPR, similarity between entanglement and black holes, etc.

So my question is: Has anyone thought about the relationship between these two geometrical structures? Are they in parallel and cooperate with each other to give a complete description of the world, or one of them is more fundamental? Where might be the tie to connect them, if there does exist a relationship between entanglement and spacetime?

There are some works to interpret the geometry of entanglement by Hopf fibre bundle or twistor structure, can these be related with the spacetime structure ?

Maybe it's just a too general question. Of course I am not expecting any definite answer here. But can anybody give some ideas?